# Inequalities of products of particular polynomials.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $y=(y_1, y_2, y_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ be a point. It's clear that $$(x_1-y_1)(x_2-y_2)\le |x-y|^2\le |x-y|^3.$$

Are the following inequalities true or false?

> $$(x_1-y_1)^2(x_2-y_2)\le |x-y|^3\tag 1$$
>
> $$(x_1-y_1)(x_2-y_2)(x_3-y_3)\le |x-y|^3 \tag 2$$
>
> $$(x_1-y_1)^3\le |x-y|^3 \tag 3$$

$x$ is a variable of components $x_1,x_2,x_3$

Comment: The choice of notation, mixing subscripts and superscripts for vector components, is unfortunate. Using superscripts as powers as well is also confusing. Consider changing $x_0 = (x_0^1, x_0^2, x_0^3)$ to $y = (y_1, y_2, y_3)$ to avoid such confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(x_i - y_i) \leq \vert x - y \vert$ for $i = 1,2,3$, since the two points $x,y$ cannot be any closer than the smallest distance between their coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I will use lower index to denote the components of a variable. To begin with, all of the inequalities are function of $y = x - x_0$, so we can write the assumption as
$$
  y_1 y_2 \leq | y |^2 \leq | y|^3.
$$
The second inequality gives us $|y|\leq 1$, which however is not relevant. Notice that $y_i, i\in \{1,2,3\}$ can be interpreted as length of edges of a cuboid and $|y|$ as the length of the body diagonal of the same cuboid. Since the body diagonal is longer than any edge of a cuboid, $y_i \leq |y|$ for $i=1,2,3$. Multiplying these inequalities in various ways gives us the inequalities (1),(2), and (3) that you want to prove. For example multiplying the inequality $y_1\leq |y|$ with itself and with the ineqaulity $y_2\leq |y|$ gives us $(y_1)^2 y_2 \leq |y|^3$, which is the inequality (1) written in terms of variable $y$.